# How to escape apostrophe in translation using jQuery and Yii2

Tags: jquery, yii2

When I do translation, due to apostrophe in translation, I am getting error in console. How to avoid the apostrophe in Jquery? I am using Yii2 platform:

```
  jQuery('body').on('click', '.page-title-toggle1', function(e) {
    var id = $(this).attr('id').split(',');
    var i = 0;
    for(i;i< id.length;i++){
        var text = $('#text-for-'+id[i]).val();
        if(text == ''){
            krajeeDialog.alert('".Yii::t("app", "Please give me a name")."<strong><i class=\"fa fa-frown-o smiley\" style=\"background-color:yellow; height:10px width:15px;\"></i></strong>');
            e.preventDefault
            return false;
        }
    }
    window.location = '".Url::base()."/index.php/templates/page-view?id=".$model->template_id."&&p_id=".$page_id."';
});
```

French translation of "please give me a name" is causing problem.

"S'il vous plaît donnez-moi un nom" - This is the French translation of "please give me a name".

Comment: If this is your PHP source code, then check generated HTML. If this is your real JS, then it won't work like this (server vs client code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to encode this string:

```
$string = \yii\helpers\Json::htmlEncode(
    Yii::t('app', 'Please give me a name')
    . '<strong><i class="fa fa-frown-o smiley" style="background-color:yellow; height:10px width:15px;"></i></strong>'
);
```

And then in your JS:

```
krajeeDialog.alert($string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try alert('S\'il vous plaît donnez-moi un nom'); in this way...